# Find and print document based on cell reference in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, database

I have a workbook in excel in which users enter data into a form and then this data is transferred into a sheet called "database"

At the end of each row in the database, there is a name of a PDF that needs to be printed. For this sake let's just pretend these PDF's are stored in the location C:\TestPDF\

These PDF Name's are stored in column S of the database sheet like so:

[Column S][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JSEL.png

I would like to automate this printing with the click of a button. There is one unique entry in the database, this is called the works order number. Therefore i would like user to enter a works order number, and then it should go through the database, find this number and print the PDF at the end of this row.

I started some code for this, and i've got to this stage:

```
Dim iRow As Long 'Variable to hold the starting row and loop through all records in database
Dim sh As Worksheet 'worksheet variable to refer  to where database is stored
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim WorksOrder As String
Dim Found As Boolean

'Get user entered WorksOrder Number

WorksOrder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PrintDocuments").Range("C3").Value

'Set worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

iRow = 2 'row in which data starts from in database

Found = False

Do While sh.Range("A" & iRow).Value <> ""  'loop through until no data is found (last row of database)
 
If WorksOrder = sh.Range("D" & iRow).Value Then

Found = True

 'Insert print pdf code here
  







Exit Do

End If

iRow = iRow + 1

Loop



If Found = True Then
MsgBox ("PDF Printed")
Else
MsgBox ("Works Order Number Not Found")
End If

End Sub
```

This code allows the user to entry a works order number in the "PrintDocuments" sheet in Cell C3. This then searches through the database and finds the works order number (column D) of the sheet "Database". I am however struggling with the inbetween bit, which is to find the PDF and print it.

As mentioned above, the PDFs are stored in C:\TestPDF\ and the name of the file is located in column S of this sheet.

so for example if the works order number was in D4, then it would find the PDF in column S4.
e.g. C:\TestPDF\"S4 value"

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried WorksheetFunction.VLookup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup

Comment: I have not, the correct PDF is already looked up based upon the works order number entered previously. This is how it is inputted into the database sheet. I assumed there should be some fairly simple code which will search the desired PDF folder, find the name based on entry in Column S, and print this document.